# How do I label these diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to put coordinates and nodes into these diagrams but they don’t appear.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{0.8}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=8pt] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\clip (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\fill[pattern=crosshatch] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}}

\scalebox{0.8}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=8pt] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm] (60:3) circle[radius=2cm];
\filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm] (60:3) circle[radius=2cm];
\clip (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\clip (60:3) circle[radius=2cm];
\fill[pattern=crosshatch] (3,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes are invisible if they are drawn outside the clipping area.

1. Either draw the nodes *before* the first `\clip` command or

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}

      % node commands

      \clip ...;
      \fill ...;
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```
2. limit the scope of the clip with environment `scope`, for example:

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     ...
     \begin{scope}
       \clip ...;
       \fill ...;
     \end{scope}

     % node commands

   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.